# "No transformation found: class io.ktor.utils.io.ByteChannelNative" error using Ktor

Tags: json, kotlin, ktor, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm trying to fetch and deserialize some data that is being hosted on [github](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Gmiller290488/kmm-demo/master/test.json).

```
{
  "Meals": [
    {
      "id": "1598044e-5259-11e9-8647-d663bd870b02",
      "name": "Tomato pasta",
      "quantity": [{
        "quantity": 1 },
        {
          "quantity": 2
        },
        {
          "quantity": 3
        }],
      "availableFromDate": "1605802429",
      "expiryDate": "1905802429",
      "info": "Vegetarian",
      "hot": false,
      "locationLat": 57.508865,
      "locationLong": -6.292,
      "distance": null
    },
    {
      "id": "2be2d854-a067-43ec-a488-2e69f0f2a624",
      "name": "Pizza",
      "quantity": [{
        "quantity": 1 },
        {
        "quantity": 2
        },
        {
          "quantity": 3
        }
      ],
      "availableFromDate": "1605802429",
      "expiryDate": "1905902429",
      "info": "Meat",
      "hot": false,
      "locationLat": 51.509465,
      "locationLong": -0.135392,
      "distance": null
    }
  ]
}
```

If I spin up a [json-server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server) locally then it works perfectly, so I know that my data class is not the problem. However when I try to do the same thing from that github link I get this error:

`Error Domain=KotlinException Code=0 "No transformation found: class io.ktor.utils.io.ByteChannelNative -> class kotlin.collections.List`

I have a feeling it might be to do with setting a ContentType or something along those lines but I haven't had any success specifying that so far.

Here is my code to make the request:

```
class MealApi {

    private val httpClient = HttpClient {
        install(JsonFeature) {
            val json = Json { ignoreUnknownKeys = true }
            serializer = KotlinxSerializer(json)
        }
    }

    suspend fun getAllMeals(): List<Meal> {
        return httpClient.get(endpoint)
    }
}
```

and here is my data class just for completeness:

```
@Serializable
data class Meal(
    @SerialName("id")
    val id: String,
    @SerialName("name")
    val name: String,
    @SerialName("quantity")
    val quantity: List<Quantity>,
    @SerialName("availableFromDate")
    var availableFromDate: String,
    @SerialName("expiryDate")
    var expiryDate: String,
    @SerialName("info")
    val info: String,
    @SerialName("hot")
    val hot: Boolean,
    @SerialName("locationLat")
    val locationLat: Float,
    @SerialName("locationLong")
    val locationLong: Float,
    @SerialName("distance")
    var distance: Double? = null
)

@Serializable
data class Quantity(
    @SerialName("quantity")
    val quantity: Int
)
```

**UPDATE**

I've found that this server https://gitcdn.link/ allows you to serve your raw github files with the right Content-Type.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've searched a lot how to change the server response headers (to change the `plain/text` one to `application/json`) but it seems that ktor actually doesn't allow to do that:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-617
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-580

A nice way should be to allow the `ResponseObserver` to change the server response headers and pass through the modify response. But you can't actually.

Your problem depends, as you pointed out, from the fact that the raw github page provides an header `Content-Type=plain/text` instead of `ContentType=application/json`.

So IRL when you are running your API in a real server this won't occur as you'll take care to put the right content type at server level.

But if you want a workaround to this you could rewrite your api call in this way:

```kotlin
suspend fun getAllMealsWithFallback() {
    var meals: Meals? = null
    try {
        meals = httpClient.get(endpoint)
    } catch (e: NoTransformationFoundException) {
        val mealsString: String = httpClient.get(endpoint)
        val json = kotlinx.serialization.json.Json {
            ignoreUnknownKeys = true
        }
        meals = json.decodeFromString(mealsString)
    } finally {
        println("Meals: ${meals?.meals}")
    }
}
```

I had to add this class to conform to the json text you have provided in the github link.

```kotlin
@Serializable
data class Meals(
    @SerialName("Meals")
    val meals: List<Meal>,
)
```

Comment: I've added the contentType also in the get. Let me know if it works. I'm not able to try it by myself right now. I'll plan to try it asap.

Comment: I'm not sure about this being a good workaround, because it seems that the api is called twice if the server does not set the right content type.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
install(JsonFeature) {
    serializer = KotlinxSerializer(KotlinJson { ignoreUnknownKeys = true })
    acceptContentTypes = acceptContentTypes + ContentType.Any
}
```

If you'd like to accept all content types. Or Use `ContentType.Text.Any`, `ContentType.Text.Html` if you preferred.

Answer (score 5):

Finally got the right working solution mentioned by this stack user @[Aleksei_Tirman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76470484) .

As user mentioned there that we can register for deserializer for particular content type (here Content-Type: text/html) to solve the problem.

```
install(ContentNegotiation) {
// ...
register(
    ContentType.Text.Html, KotlinxSerializationConverter(
        Json {
            prettyPrint = true
            isLenient = true
            ignoreUnknownKeys = true
        } 
     ) 
  ) 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Ktor 2.0, you would need `ContentNegotiation` plugin instead of `JsonFeature`.

For example if you use Gson:

```kotlin
install(io.ktor.client.plugins.contentnegotiation.ContentNegotiation) {
    gson()
}
```

Comment: from version 2.0.0, `JsonFeature` has expired in favour of `ContentNegotiation`. Official guide https://ktor.io/docs/migrating-2.html#serialization-client

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround for ktor version 2.0.3 you can create you own `AppContentNegotiation` class and in the `scope.responsePipeline.intercept` provide needed `contentType`

```
/**
 * A plugin that serves two primary purposes:
 * - Negotiating media types between the client and server. For this, it uses the `Accept` and `Content-Type` headers.
 * - Serializing/deserializing the content in a specific format when sending requests and receiving responses.
 *    Ktor supports the following formats out-of-the-box: `JSON`, `XML`, and `CBOR`.
 *
 * You can learn more from [Content negotiation and serialization](https://ktor.io/docs/serialization-client.html).
 */
public class AppContentNegotiation internal constructor(
    internal val registrations: List<Config.ConverterRegistration>
) {

    /**
     * A [ContentNegotiation] configuration that is used during installation.
     */
    public class Config : Configuration {

        internal class ConverterRegistration(
            val converter: ContentConverter,
            val contentTypeToSend: ContentType,
            val contentTypeMatcher: ContentTypeMatcher,
        )

        internal val registrations = mutableListOf<ConverterRegistration>()

        /**
         * Registers a [contentType] to a specified [converter] with an optional [configuration] script for a converter.
         */
        public override fun <T : ContentConverter> register(
            contentType: ContentType,
            converter: T,
            configuration: T.() -> Unit
        ) {
            val matcher = when (contentType) {
                ContentType.Application.Json -> JsonContentTypeMatcher
                else -> defaultMatcher(contentType)
            }
            register(contentType, converter, matcher, configuration)
        }

        /**
         * Registers a [contentTypeToSend] and [contentTypeMatcher] to a specified [converter] with
         * an optional [configuration] script for a converter.
         */
        public fun <T : ContentConverter> register(
            contentTypeToSend: ContentType,
            converter: T,
            contentTypeMatcher: ContentTypeMatcher,
            configuration: T.() -> Unit
        ) {
            val registration = ConverterRegistration(
                converter.apply(configuration),
                contentTypeToSend,
                contentTypeMatcher
            )
            registrations.add(registration)
        }

        private fun defaultMatcher(pattern: ContentType): ContentTypeMatcher =
            object : ContentTypeMatcher {
                override fun contains(contentType: ContentType): Boolean =
                    contentType.match(pattern)
            }
    }

    /**
     * A companion object used to install a plugin.
     */
    @KtorDsl
    public companion object Plugin : HttpClientPlugin<Config, AppContentNegotiation > {
        public override val key: AttributeKey<AppContentNegotiation> =
            AttributeKey("ContentNegotiation")

        override fun prepare(block: Config.() -> Unit): AppContentNegotiation {
            val config = Config().apply(block)
            return AppContentNegotiation(config.registrations)
        }

        override fun install(plugin: AppContentNegotiation, scope: HttpClient) {
            scope.requestPipeline.intercept(HttpRequestPipeline.Transform) { payload ->
                val registrations = plugin.registrations
                registrations.forEach { context.accept(it.contentTypeToSend) }

                if (subject is OutgoingContent || DefaultIgnoredTypes.any { it.isInstance(payload) }) {
                    return@intercept
                }
                val contentType = context.contentType() ?: return@intercept

                if (payload is Unit) {
                    context.headers.remove(HttpHeaders.ContentType)
                    proceedWith(EmptyContent)
                    return@intercept
                }

                val matchingRegistrations =
                    registrations.filter { it.contentTypeMatcher.contains(contentType) }
                        .takeIf { it.isNotEmpty() } ?: return@intercept
                if (context.bodyType == null) return@intercept
                context.headers.remove(HttpHeaders.ContentType)

                // Pick the first one that can convert the subject successfully
                val serializedContent = matchingRegistrations.firstNotNullOfOrNull { registration ->
                    registration.converter.serialize(
                        contentType,
                        contentType.charset() ?: Charsets.UTF_8,
                        context.bodyType!!,
                        payload
                    )
                } ?: throw ContentConverterException(
                    "Can't convert $payload with contentType $contentType using converters " +
                            matchingRegistrations.joinToString { it.converter.toString() }
                )

                proceedWith(serializedContent)
            }

            scope.responsePipeline.intercept(HttpResponsePipeline.Transform) { (info, body) ->
                if (body !is ByteReadChannel) return@intercept
                if (info.type == ByteReadChannel::class) return@intercept

                // !!!!!!! Provide desired content type here
                val contentType = <HERE> // default implementation is - context.response.contentType() ?: return@intercept

                val registrations = plugin.registrations
                val matchingRegistrations = registrations
                    .filter { it.contentTypeMatcher.contains(contentType) }
                    .takeIf { it.isNotEmpty() } ?: return@intercept

                // Pick the first one that can convert the subject successfully
                val parsedBody = matchingRegistrations.firstNotNullOfOrNull { registration ->
                    registration.converter
                        .deserialize(context.request.headers.suitableCharset(), info, body)
                } ?: return@intercept
                val response = HttpResponseContainer(info, parsedBody)
                proceedWith(response)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then install it for `HttpClient`

```
HttpClient {
    install(AppContentNegotiation) {
        json(json)
        addDefaultResponseValidation()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

on my side, I decided to stop using the `ContentNegotiation` altogether because it would always complain or throw an error that the content type is wrong, or sometimes something else. I know the backend I use sucks and would sometimes respond a json even though the content type was set to text/html, but I cannot change it, and I just need to parse it. so I simply get the response as text, and then parse it using kotlinx.serialization:

```kotlin
val httpClient = HttpClient()
val jsonSerializer = Json {
    ignoreUnknownKeys = true
    isLenient = false
}


val response: HttpResponse = httpClient.request(apiUrl) {
    method = HttpMethod.Get
    //...
}

val responseBody = response.bodyAsText()
return jsonSerializer.decodeFromString(responseBody)
```

Answer (score 1):

In case the issue is the Content-Type:

You can alter the list of response content types, for which the `KotlinxSerializer` gets active, by extending the `JsonFeature` block to:

```
install(JsonFeature) {
    val json = Json { ignoreUnknownKeys = true }
    serializer = KotlinxSerializer(json)
    receiveContentTypeMatchers += object : ContentTypeMatcher {
        override fun contains(contentType: ContentType): Boolean =
            contentType == ContentType("text", "plain")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

2023 - Fresh answer after searching 2 hours:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideHttpClient(): HttpClient {

    return HttpClient(Android) {
        install(Logging) {
            level = LogLevel.ALL
        }
        install(JsonFeature) {
            val json = kotlinx.serialization.json.Json { ignoreUnknownKeys = true }
            serializer = KotlinxSerializer(json)
            acceptContentTypes = acceptContentTypes + ContentType.Any
        }
    }
```

Then get your request and done!

```
httpClient.get { url("https://itunes.apple.com/search?media=music&entity=album&term=eminem") }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this exception was thrown when I was attempting to access the `body()` potion of the HTTP response as such:

```
val httpResponse = httpClient.post(urlString) { ... }
val body = httpResponse.body<YourExpectedSerializableResponseType>
```

In the happy path scenario, the server would return a body that matched `YourExpectedSerializableResponseType` and everything would work as expected.

However, for a particular edge case that returned a different (still considered successful) status code, the server returned an empty response body. Since the client was expecting a response body and in this case, there wasn't any, this exception was thrown because it could not serialize an empty response body to the expected type `YourExpectedSerializableResponseType`.

**My recommendation:** In addition to ensuring your server is returning the type you expect to serialize/consume on your client, confirm your server is **actually returning an object**.

***Internal Dialogue:** I wonder if this exception could be more clear in this case as the issue is more so that the client expected a response body to exist and less so that an empty response body ("") couldn't be serialized into an expected type - especially given that an empty response body isn't even valid JSON. Hm.*