# io.ktor.client.call.NoTransformationFound:class io.ktor.utils.io.ByteBufferChannel(Kotlin reflection is not available)

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor

I'm using Ktor in my KMM project
When i try to parse the json response from api always i get this exception but if i make the response return String it work.

Here is code of method:

```
    suspend fun getSkoolURL22(code:String, token:String): GetSchoolResponse {
     
        return clientv.submitForm(
                url = "$CONST_SCHOOL_VERIFICATION_URL.",
                formParameters = Parameters.build {
                    append("token", token)
                    append("skool_code", code)
                }).body() }
```

This is the client:

```
 val clientv = HttpClient() {
        install(Logging) {
            logger = Logger.SIMPLE
            level = LogLevel.ALL  }
        install(ContentNegotiation) {
            json(Json {
                prettyPrint = true
                isLenient = true
                ignoreUnknownKeys = true
            })
        }
```

And this my data Class:

```
@Serializable
data class GetSchoolResponse(
    @Serializable
    val code: Int,
    @Serializable
    val data: List<Data>,
    @Serializable
    val message: String) {
    @Serializable
    data class Data(
        @Serializable
        val domain: String,
        @Serializable
        val id: Int,
        @Serializable
        val ip: String,
        @Serializable
        val sk_code: Int,
        @Serializable
        val sk_name: String)
}
```

I got this exception:

```
io.ktor.client.call.NoTransformationFoundException: No transformation found: class io.ktor.utils.io.ByteBufferChannel (Kotlin reflection is not available) -> class com.example.skoolkmm.data.GetSchoolResponse (Kotlin reflection is not available)

 status: 200 OK
    response headers: 
    content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    , date: Sun, 11 Jun 2023 21:21:11 GMT
    , server: Apache
    , transfer-encoding: chunked
    , vary: Accept-Encoding
    , x-iplb-instance: 38231
    , x-iplb-request-id: C4B34E62:51E4_36245B3E:0050_64863AC7_0DE2:25792
    , x-powered-by: PHP/7.0
```

This is my server Response

2023-06-11 22:21:10.229 19455-19511/com.example.skoolkmm.android I/System.out: -> content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
2023-06-11 22:21:10.229 19455-19511/com.example.skoolkmm.android I/System.out: -> date: Sun, 11 Jun 2023 21:21:11 GMT
2023-06-11 22:21:10.229 19455-19511/com.example.skoolkmm.android I/System.out: -> server: Apache
2023-06-11 22:21:10.229 19455-19511/com.example.skoolkmm.android I/System.out: -> transfer-encoding: chunked
2023-06-11 22:21:10.229 19455-19511/com.example.skoolkmm.android I/System.out: -> vary: Accept-Encoding
2023-06-11 22:21:10.229 19455-19511/com.example.skoolkmm.android I/System.out: -> x-iplb-instance: 38231
2023-06-11 22:21:10.229 19455-19511/com.example.skoolkmm.android I/System.out: -> x-iplb-request-id: C4B34E62:51E4_36245B3E:0050_64863AC7_0DE2:25792
2023-06-11 22:21:10.229 19455-19511/com.example.skoolkmm.android I/System.out: -> x-powered-by: PHP/7.0
2023-06-11 22:21:10.229 19455-19511/com.example.skoolkmm.android I/System.out: BODY Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
2023-06-11 22:21:10.229 19455-19511/com.example.skoolkmm.android I/System.out: BODY START
2023-06-11 22:21:10.230 19455-19511/com.example.skoolkmm.android I/System.out: {"code":200,"message":"success","data":[{"id":1,"domain":"https://dev.vyzyoschool.com/","ip":"197.13.17.67","sk_code":111111,"sk_name":"VYZYO"}]}
2023-06-11 22:21:10.230 19455-19511/com.example.skoolkmm.android I/System.out: BODY END

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: io.ktor.client.call.NoTransformationFoundException: No transformation found: class io.ktor.utils.io.ByteBufferChannel (Kotlin reflection is not available) -> class com.example.skoolkmm.data.GetSchoolResponse (Kotlin reflection is not available)

Comment: Can you please share the response from the server?

Comment: Done i added the server response on the question bellow

Comment: It seems like the problem is that the server replies with the `Content-Type: text/html` but the `Content-Type: application/json` is expected. Do you have control over the server?

Comment: no i don't have a control over the server, can I fix it on the source code?

Answer (score 1):

Since the server replies with the `Content-Type: text/html` and the JSON data, you can register a deserializer for this particular content type to solve the problem:

```
install(ContentNegotiation) {
    // ...
    register(
        ContentType.Text.Html, KotlinxSerializationConverter(
            Json {
                prettyPrint = true
                isLenient = true
                ignoreUnknownKeys = true
            }
        )
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you but i got this Error now:
    kotlinx.serialization.SerializationException: Serializer for class 'GetSchoolResponse' is not found.
    Mark the class as @Serializable or provide the serializer explicitly.

Comment: My gradle contain: 
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization:$ktor_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json:$ktor_version")
    //serialization
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:$kotlinxSerializationVersion")

Comment: Please check that you can deserialize JSON data to your `GetSchoolResponse` class without Ktor by using only the https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization library.

Comment: I'm Serializing using import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
but i got this error

Comment: I mean, can you successfully deserialize JSON to your class without using Ktor?

Comment: You mean i keep return type as String then I deserialize this String into Json ?