# Ktor fails to parse json for api response because of "text/html" content-type at response header

Tags: kotlin, ktor, ktor-client

I use Ktor (2.3.4) to send an api request to a server that returns json data. Unfortunately, the server put **content-type "text/html"** instead of **"application/json"** at headers which causes ktor to fail returned content.

Seems Ktor uses "content-type" at response header to choose deserializer so the exception is expected

I thought that overriding response's header might fix the problem but unfortunately didn't make any change

```
val client = HttpClient(OkHttp) {
        install(ContentNegotiation) {
            gson()
        }

    engine {
        addInterceptor { chain ->
            val request = chain.request()

            val response = chain.proceed(request)

            val header = response.headers.newBuilder()
                .add("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .build()

            response.newBuilder()
                .headers(header)
                .build()
        }
    }
```

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65105118/no-transformation-found-class-io-ktor-utils-io-bytechannelnative-error-using) post as a similar issue but the suggested solutions are not fixed the problem.

I wonder how I could parse json api response using ktor with content-type "text/html" at headers ?

Answer (score 0):

You can either receive the body as a string and deserialize it or register a content converter for the `text/html` content type:

```
install(ContentNegotiation) {
    register(ContentType.Text.Html, GsonConverter(GsonBuilder().create()))
    gson()
}
```

Comment: I have a similar issue but in my case the server simply does not send any content-type header. So ktor never deserializes. How can I tell Ktor to always using a given deserializer?
I tried with register(  ContentType.Any, KotinxSerializationConverter(

Comment: @BastiX You can try with: `json(contentType = ContentType.Any)`

Comment: If the server doesn't send the Content-Type header you can receive the response body as a String and then deserialize it.

Comment: @Kamil Thx for responding! I think I tried ContentType.Any but the contentType I got was null and so that didn't work. I got my serverguy to simply always set a header :)